# Is there a better way of POST/PUT-ing entity filed that is array of objects than JSON.stringify(array)?

Tags: json, express, restful-architecture

In my case I send entity notes array in a request body field as:

```
{
  "currency": "USD",
  "notes": "[{\"title\":\"note title 000\", \"content\":\"content 000\"},
    {\"title\":\"note title 001\", \"content\":\"content 001\"},
    {\"title\":\"note title 002\", \"content\":\"content 002\"}]"
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you from just sending the array as-is?

Comment: I have adjusted the code to accept array as is.